# How i hide db user name and password in AWS EC2 using terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

i have this code in 'dev.tfvars' terraform file with the database login data of an AWS EC2 instance in clear text.

```
ssm_values = {
  db_password = "admin123"
  db_name     = "tfdb"
  db_username = "admin"
}
```

how can i hide them?

Comment: By not using TF. First set some dummy passwords in TF, then use local-exec to change them to proper ones.

Comment: You need secrets management.

Comment: Why are you calling them `ssm_values` if you aren't storing the values in AWS SSM?

Answer (score 1):

You can store the sensitive fields like password in AWS SSM and then use [ssm data source resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/ssm_parameter) to retrieve value.

Something like this:

```
data "aws_ssm_parameter" "db-password" {
  name =  "/db/password"
  with_decryption = true
}
```

You can reference to this value this way:

```
data.aws_ssm_parameter.db-password.value
```